# Access ENUM from HIVE to IMPALA without changing the existing HIVE schema

Tags: hadoop, enums, hive, impala

**Requirement:** I have a HIVE table which has ENUM datatype and would like to access the same from IMPALA environment.

**Blocker:** As IMPALA does not support ENUM I could not access the data from HIVE table.

**Restriction:** Should not change the existing HIVE schema.

*Can some one please take a look and suggest me the way I can resolve this issue ?*

**Code snippet**:(In Impala)

ABC is HIVE table

enum_col datatype is ENUM

invalidate metadata ABC;

select enum_col from ABC;

**Error:** 
TableLoadingException: Failed to load metadata for table: ABC CAUSED BY: 
AnalysisException: Unsupported type 'enum' of column 'enum_col'

**Ways I've tried:**  None of them do work

select cast(enum_col as string)  from ABC;

select coalesce (cast(enum_col as string), null)  from ABC;

Comment: Can you make a Hive view that impala would query?

Comment: you have to refresh the underlined table's metadata each time from Impala even if you create the VIEW. That will cause the same issue